# ListViewWebPart could not be found

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to define the following variable in my C#, but am getting the missing using or assembly error.

`private ListViewWebPart lvwp;`

I'm including the below using statements. ListViewWebPart should be in Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages. I do have the Microsoft.SharePoint reference.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;
```

(SharePoint 2010, Visual Studio 2012)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was using this in a sandboxed solution, which you can't do. Leaving this as an answer in case anyone else stares at this problem for 6 hours without figuring this out.